# How to configure JAVA_HOME from Windows at shell script

Tags: java, windows, shell

I want to run a jar file from shell script. But current operating system is Windows. So, how to configure to know `JAVA_HOME` in shell script. I want to know how to export `JAVA_HOME` from Windows in shell script.
Path for `JDK` in Windows is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java`
When I run shell program I got the following error:

> Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32: command not found

Comment: SET JAVA_HOME = path_to_your_jdk

Comment: What happens when you enter "java -version" in the command line?

Comment: The error message indicates that you did not properly quote the blank in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

The path to your JDK = JAVA_HOME is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32` .
You have to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to PATH.

These lines could be part of your shell script:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can set these variables from a script, on Windows the normal way is to set them machine-wide.

Right-click on your computer icon in explorer. Select "Properties", then "Advanced System Settings", then "Environment Variables".

Add a variable with the name `JAVA_HOME` and the value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32`

Find the `PATH` variable and append `;%JAVA_HOME\bin` (including the semicolon) to it.

More detailed instructions on setting path and environment variables on Windows are available here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm